# How to integrate online tutorial 'chatty' by Joseph Ndungu to an existing Rails 3 app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Joseph Ndungu's tutorial found here: http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails

I am also trying to integrate this into my own rails 3 application.

So far the chat box appears and I am able to send a message, however when I press enter in the chatbox I get an error.

Initially it was that an index action was missing in the Messages Controller, but I added that action and now I get

Template is missing

```
Missing template messages/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee,   :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *   "/home/eiskarlsson/repos/MyLexikon.com/app/views" *   "/home/eiskarlsson/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.5.10/app/views"
```

I am not sure how to go about this. Should I add a template, if I do so what would I have to put in it? Or maybe the tutorial is correct and I am missing something?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

The jQuery file is: users.js:

```
(function(jQuery) {
var ready = function () {

    /**
     * When the send message link on our home page is clicked
     * send an ajax request to our rails app with the sender_id and
     * recipient_id
     */

    jQuery('.start-conversation').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var sender_id = jQuery(this).data('sid');
        var recipient_id = jQuery(this).data('rip');

        jQuery.post("/conversations", { sender_id: sender_id, recipient_id: recipient_id }, function (data) {
            chatBox.chatWith(data.conversation_id);
        });
    });

    /**
     * Used to minimize the chatbox
     */

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.toggleChatBox', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = jQuery(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.toggleChatBoxGrowth(id);
    });

    /**
     * Used to close the chatbox
     */

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.closeChat', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = jQuery(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.close(id);
    });


    /**
     * Listen on keypress' in our chat textarea and call the
     * chatInputKey in chat.js for inspection
     */

    jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.chatboxtextarea', function (event) {

        var id = jQuery(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.checkInputKey(event, jQuery(this), id);
    });

    /**
     * When a conversation link is clicked show up the respective
     * conversation chatbox
     */

    jQuery('a.conversation').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var conversation_id = jQuery(this).data('cid');
        chatBox.chatWith(conversation_id);
    });


}



    jQuery(document).ready(ready);
    jQuery(document).on('page:load', ready);
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the Messages controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

# def index
#   @users = User.where('id != ?',current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')
#   @conversations = Conversation.involving(current_user).order('created_at DESC')
# end

def create
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  @message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
  @message.user_id = current_user.id
  @message.save!

  @path = conversation_path(@conversation)
end

private

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body)
end
end
```

Comment: Your form. Did you forget to put a `remote: true` on it? It's not being sent via ajax.

Comment: Actually there is a template in views/messages called create.js.erb, but it seems that rails cannot find it.

Comment: Yes, because your form is being sent as a regular full-page-refresh POST, not ajax.

Comment: I added remote: true to users/index.html.erb, but I get the same error

Comment: Must be that you missed some step from the tutorial. I suggest going over it again, paying twice as much attention. If that doesn't help, post enough details to help us see the problem (like definition of your form, for example). But not too much details.

Comment: OK. I'll go over it again, even though I did that several times already. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I checked with the tutorial and I don't think that I am missing a step.

Comment: Are you sure? Post your view/jquery then

Comment: Yes, these look fine. Then the problem is in your conversations_controller create action. Show it.

Comment: Ah damn, it's _messages_, not _conversations_. I'm afraid you'll need to remove these view and controller (as it's irrelevant) and add instead the view for your chat window and the messages controller.

Comment: And the view for chat form?

Comment: https://github.com/Joseph-N/chatty/blob/master/app/views/messages/create.js.erb

Comment: No-no, the form, with the text input.

Comment: https://github.com/Joseph-N/chatty/blob/master/app/views/conversations/show.html.erb

Comment: Yep, this one. Now that's __his__ form. Show me yours.

Comment: It is the same. I copied and pasted it :-)

Comment: Ok, this must mean that `remote: true` doesn't have any effect. Do you have jquery-ujs properly enabled? Consult this page: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: I checked the link you gave me and jquery-ujs seems to be properly installed as a gem.

Comment: And the rest of the installation?

Comment: I have followed the installation labeled: 'Installation using the jquery-rails gem'. Do I need to do anything more?

Comment: the application.js line is pretty important.

Comment: It is there. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas. :)